# pandas apply groupby and agg, and update orig columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
   Group1.  Group2  Val
0      1      Q      2
1      1      Q      3
2      2      R      8
3      4      Y      9
```

I want to update df with list of values per group, so new df will be

```
   Group   Group2   Val     new
0      1    Q        2     [2, 3]
1      1    Q        3     [2, 3]
2      2    R        8     [8]
3      4    Y        9     [9]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: My code already works for your updated example (you don't need to group by Group2 here). If you want to have a good example for 2 columns grouper use Q for the first 2 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) directly, so [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) (or `merge` if you have several groupers):

```
df['new'] = df['Group'].map(df.groupby('Group')['Val'].agg(list))
```

Output:

```
   Group  Val     new
0      1    2  [2, 3]
1      1    3  [2, 3]
2      2    8     [8]
3      4    9     [9]
```

Using several columns to group:

```
cols = ['Group1', 'Group2']
df['new'] = df.merge(df.groupby(cols)['Val'].agg(list),
                     left_on=cols, right_index=True, how='left')['Val_y']
```

Example:

```
   Group1 Group2  Val     new
0       1      Q    2  [2, 3]
1       1      Q    3  [2, 3]   # used Q here as example
2       2      R    8     [8]
3       4      Y    9     [9]
```

Comment: I get the error 'Error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'' because I have multiple keys. Please see the edit

Comment: @Cranjis then you would need to `merge` as I hinted in my answer, let me update it ;) **Although your updated example does not require to group by Group2**

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use `transform` which I think may be a little bit slower than `map` in other answer or may not be. Just in case you want to know how to do it:

```
df['new'] = df.assign(
    Vals=df['Val'].values.reshape(-1, 1).tolist()
    ).groupby('Group1')['Vals'].transform(sum)

print(df)

   Group1 Group2  Val     new
0       1      Q    2  [2, 3]
1       1      T    3  [2, 3]
2       2      R    8     [8]
3       4      Y    9     [9]
```

The transient `Vals` column looks like:

```
0    [2]
1    [3]
2    [8]
3    [9]
Name: Vals, dtype: object
```